# Using juice as bottling sugar

Tags: bottle-conditioning, priming-sugar

So, I have brewed a big batch of kombucha. Normally, the original gravity is 1.020.  But this time, I created a 1.016 batch.  After nine days, the gravity went to 1.014 and the pH to 3.4.  The kombucha organisms which produce acetic acid, the collagen? scoby, and carbonation leave a lot of residual sugar.  So, as an experiment, I am adding brett to eat that sugar.  I moved it into secondary fermentation and added Brett Trois.  When that is done, I will then bottle it.  I used a bottling calculator as follows:

> Amount Being Packaged:  3 g / 11.3562 l
>
> Volumes of CO2:         3.0
>
> Temperature of Beer:    75F / 23.8889C
>
> CO2 in Beer:            0.78 volumes
>
> Priming Table Sugar:    3.6 oz / 100.9 g

Instead of using sucrose for the bottling sugar, I want to add 32 ounces of Just Tart Cherry juice.  With a total of four servings which lists 24 grams of sugars per serving.  That should total 96 grams.  Will the cherry juice successfully bottle condition this batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The juice is (one of) the key factors - Is it pure juice?  No preservatives?  No artificial sweeteners?  Nothing but cherry juice, right?  So long as that is the case then you're good on that front -

However, I'd cut back a little if I were you as brett will eat more than regular yeast - from [The Mad Fermantationist](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2012/08/bottle-conditioning-with-brett-belgian.html):

> The two common species of Brettanomyces used in brewing (anomalous/claussenii and bruxellensis/lambicus) both produce an enzyme that allows them to ferment carbohydrates (dextrins) up to nine glucose molecules long (brewer's yeast can only ferment chains up to three glucose molecules long - maltotriose). With too much residual gravity remaining the Brett will over-carbonated the beer given time, which can result in gushing or even bottle bombs.

and 'regular yeast' is likely what that bottle sugar calculator is calculating based on.  But first question is the biggest - make sure you have 100% nothing-but-cherry juice.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Juice from concentrate and water. http://www.rwknudsenfamily.com/products/just-juice/organic-just-tart-cherry and thanks for the Mad Fermantationist link!

Comment: yeah, looks like you're good :) if it helped, please check my answer so it's out of the 'unanswered' queue

Comment: Ah, didn't know to check an answer. Thanks again.